# Get current route in Next.js API route

Tags: next.js

I want to access my current route (eg `/[user_id]/posts`) for both regular pages and APIs, so that I can log it in errors, increase page hit counters, etc.

The only automated way I found to retrieve the current route involves `useRouter`, but that is only accessible in React components.

I want to avoid hardcoding a route in each of my handlers as that can get out of sync easily.

How can I automate retrieving the current route inside a handler?

Comment: What do you mean by "handler"? Do you want to access the current route on the server-side?

Comment: @juliomalves yes. I have an entry point for a given url path on the server side (a handler/controller). When that entry point is hit, I want to access the route that matched it.

Comment: Do you mean like what `req.url` returns? That's accessible in `getServerSideProps` and on the API routes.

Comment: @juliomalves that works except it substitutes param, e.g. I get `/1515/posts` instead of `/[user_id]/posts`. My intent is to use this as an aggregation key in server logs, it doesnt work when cardinality explodes like that

Answer (score 0):

It's simply not supported by the framework. There are 2 alternatives I found:

1/ Use another framework such as Nest.js. With Nest, you can access router information in an interceptor. E.g. with the Fastify adapter:

```js
@Injectable()
export class InstrumentationInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
  intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Observable<unknown> {
    return next.handle().pipe(
      tap(() => {
        const ctx = context.switchToHttp();
        console.log(ctx.getRequest().routerPath);
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

2/ Create your own controller infrastructure and attach metadata to each controller, e.g.:

```js
export class UserController extends BaseController {
  getRoute(): string {
    return "/user/:userid";
  }
}
```

Note that you will need to manually keep routes in sync with your file structure. The above can be coded via Decorators too.

3?/ Theoretically you can configure a [Custom Server](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-server) in Nest and use a router that supports retrieving route paths, with a hook for you to retrieve the route (e.g. attach it to the request object during a middleware). If you find yourself doing this though, take a look at 1/.